# Shapes on coordinated question GCSE

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, coordinate-systems, word-problem

I am struggling with this question where I don't know how to use the coordinate of A and B on the square to work out the coordinate of D.
I found that it could be (2, -1) because of where the x and y coordinates are but It was incorrect.

Question:
[image: Question]

Thank You and help is appreciated

How would I work the coordinated out?

Comment: Use that AD and AB are perpendicular and side lengths of a square are equal

Comment: i still dont understand

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

look at the figure

[image]

and note that the triangles $AEB$, $BFD$, $DGC$,$CHA$ are equal.

Comment: how could I use knowing that the triangles are equal to work out coordinate of D

Comment: Using the fact that for $AEB$ you know $AE$ and $EB$.

Comment: how would I work out what cm AE AND EB are the sides

Comment: im really confused

Comment: is there another method to work out D

Comment: @aspaering this is a simpler approach. Using different lengths of sides of triangle like EB, AH, try to conclude about coordinates. A is 1 units left of B so D is 1 units down of A. So y coordinate of D is 3-1=2. Similarly A is 4 units above B so D is 4 units left of A. X coordinate of D is -2.

Comment: Emilio there's a discrepancy in your image and op.

Comment: @King Tut: Yes sorry, I' changed $C$ and $D$ but  this  does not change the method.

Comment: Obviously. My up votes are recharged.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is:

> D(x,y) : Tell me when you have got somewhere, and I will edit it in.

Step 1: Find how you get from A to B with a vector

Step 2: Rotate AB $90^\circ$ clockwise

Step 3: Put this vector on $A$ to find $D$

Comment: Is vector AB (2                                                                                                                 3)

Comment: @AspaeringStar7 nope

Comment: um is the vector (2 -2 )

Comment: No,  I meant BA.

Comment: is vector (2 -4)

Comment: or i the vector ( -2 4 )

Comment: actually how do I find the vector of a line with two coordinates

Comment: Please don't spam me with answers. This is the comments section; if you really want help that you would like constant contact with you should look at forums instead.

Comment: ok i got the vector  (1 2) after doing step two how o I do step 3

Comment: Just realised something was wrong. I've corrected it now.

Comment: do I times vector by 90 to rotate vector

Comment: please can you put the step by step solutions as I am getting confused if you can

Comment: ok using a method that line AB is perpendicular to line DC so I times the coordinates of AB and DC by -1 so the new coordinates are (-2,-3) and (-4,1) there fore coordinates D are (-2,1). Is that a valid method?